# VB.NET Form1_Load and Button_Click keeps throwing Nullreference Error

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception

Not extremely experienced with Windows Forms applications (this is the first I am trying to build) but I just can't figure out while my app keeps throwing nullreference errors on Form1_Load and 2 of the 7 Browsebutton_Click Subs. The other 5 work perfectly.

Additional info:

- The non-working buttons I added later to my application
- Both on Form1_Load and clicking the 2 non-working Browse-button
  return the    same errors: System.NullreferenceException: "Object
  reference not set    to an instance of an object"
- When testing the app in VS everything    works totally fine, however
  after I build the solution, install it    and run it on my computer
  the errors appear

**AppConfig file appsettings-part looks like this (verfied all the paths and they do exist):**

```
<appSettings>
<add key="LastZHRverzamelPDF" value="C:\x\pdf files\TestPDF.pdf" />
<add key="LastMapSplitted" value="C:\x\pdf files\ZHRFORMS" />
<add key="LastPersFile" value="C:\x\pdf files\Personeelslijst.xlsx" />
<add key="LastMap1" value="C:\x\pdf files\Salarisslips" />
<add key="LastMap2" value="C:\x\pdf files\Vakantie-uren" />
<add key="LastMap3" value="C:\x\pdf files\ZHRFORMS" />
<add key="LastMap4" value="C:\x\pdf files\Logitime" />
<add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
</appSettings>
```

**Form1_Load procedure contains the folliwing code:**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try

        'Laatstgekozen waarden uit app.config halen en in lbls neerzetten
        lblZHRFile.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LastZHRverzamelPDF").ToString()
        lblMapSplitted.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LastMapSplitted").ToString() & "\"

        lblPersFile.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LastPersFile").ToString()
        lblMap1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LastMap1").ToString() & "\"
        lblMap2.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LastMap2").ToString() & "\"
        lblMap3.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LastMap3").ToString() & "\"
        lblMap4.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LastMap4").ToString() & "\"

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim exMsg As String = "Message: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & "Source: " & ex.Source & vbCrLf & "StackTrace: " & ex.StackTrace
        MsgBox(exMsg, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Sub Form1_Load")
        Dim errormsg As String = ex.Message

    End Try

End Sub
```

I'm loading the appconfig values into the UserForm-labels here to display the last chosen values. Next to the 7 labels I have 7 Browse-buttons to modify the paths. The 2 of them that **don't** work contain the following  code:

```
Private Sub btnZHRPath_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnZHRPath.Click
    Try
        Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
        fd.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LastZHRverzamelPDF").ToString()
        Dim strFileName As String

        With fd
            .Title = "Selecteer verzamel-PDF file ZHRFORMS uit SAP"
            .InitialDirectory = ""
            .Filter = "All files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.pdf)|*.pdf"
            .FilterIndex = 2
            .RestoreDirectory = True
        End With
        If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            strFileName = fd.FileName
            lblZHRFile.Text = strFileName
            Dim objConfig As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
            objConfig.AppSettings.Settings("LastZHRverzamelPDF").Value = strFileName
            objConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
        Else
            lblZHRFile.Text = "(overslaan)"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim exMsg As String = "Message: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & "Source: " & ex.Source & vbCrLf & "StackTrace: " & ex.StackTrace
        MsgBox(exMsg, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "btnZHRPath_Click")

    End Try
End Sub
```

Also not working for the same reason:

```
 Private Sub btnSplittedPath_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSplittedPath.Click

    Try
        If sender = Nothing Then MsgBox("nullsender")
        lblMapSplitted.Text = "C:\" 'ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LastMapSplitted").ToString() & "\"

        Dim Map As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog
        Map.SelectedPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LastMapSplitted").ToString()
        Map.Description = "Selecteer doelmap voor gesplitte PDF-files"
        Map.ShowNewFolderButton = True
        Dim DoelMap As String = ""
        If Map.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            DoelMap = Map.SelectedPath & "\"
            Dim objConfig As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
            objConfig.AppSettings.Settings("LastMapSplitted").Value = Map.SelectedPath
            objConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
        Else
            DoelMap = "(overslaan)"
        End If
        lblMapSplitted.Text = DoelMap
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim exMsg As String = "Message: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & "Source: " & ex.Source & vbCrLf & "StackTrace: " & ex.StackTrace
        MsgBox(exMsg, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "btnSplittedPath_Click")

    End Try
End Sub
```

Strange enough this Browse-button **does** work correctly (like the remaining 4 with similar code):

```
Private Sub btnFilePath_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFilePath.Click

    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim strFileName As String
    fd.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LastPersFile").ToString()
    With fd
        .Title = "Selecteer bestand met medewerkergegevens"
        .InitialDirectory = ""
        .Filter = "All files (*.xl*)|*.xl*|All files (*.xl*)|*.xl*"
        .FilterIndex = 2
        .RestoreDirectory = True
    End With
    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        strFileName = fd.FileName
        lblPersFile.Text = strFileName
        Dim objConfig As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
        objConfig.AppSettings.Settings("LastPersFile").Value = strFileName
        objConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
    End If

End Sub
```

Tried everything to fix this but simply can't figure out why my app keeps throwing these errors at me!! Please help me out here!

Comment: Don't post whole of the code in your question, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225698/is-it-correct-to-post-whole-of-the-code-in-question)

Comment: Do you have any "OnTextChanged" events connected to the textboxes? Your appsettings contains no issues from what I can tell.

Comment: Hi Wozze, no OnTextChanged-event added on any of the textboxes... It gets even weirder now, installed my program at a second computer and no problems at all, everything works totally fine..... NullReferenceException appears to be local, any ideas?